# Why is the IP "92.242.140.21" connecting to one of my ports? Is it Malware?

Tags: networking

When I start up Chrome, "netstat -taupen" shows 92.242.140.21 connecting to a random port number, usually above 20,000. The IP is from the UK and is tied to Barefruit Ltd. Exactly what is connecting this IP to my computer when I use Chrome?  If it has something to do with the ISP,  I use Verizon.

Here is the terminal shows

```
Local Address        Foreign Address     State        User   Inode    PID/Program Name
192.168.1.3:33883    92.242.140.21:80     TIME_WAIT    0      0        -
```

Also

```
Local Address        Foreign Address     State        User   Inode    PID/Program Name
192.168.1.3:33881    92.242.140.21:80     TIME_WAIT    0      0        -
```

Comment: ^I am sorry if it seems like a duplicate, but that question dealt with a different IP address. I am only asking what is causing a connection between my computer and "92.242.140.21".

Comment: Google shows some threads if you search for that IP. Here someone claimed he saw connection to that IP after his router was hacked: http://forums.verizon.com/t5/FiOS-Internet/FIOS-DNS-Hack-Directed-to-unallocated-barefruit-co-uk92-242-140/td-p/723697/page/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small search will reveal that this IP belongs to Barefruit Ltd.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barefruit):

> Barefruit works with Internet Service Providers (ISPs) and major
>   portals to use a range of software solutions which modify the ISPs DNS
>   service such as the BIND software and also a specialist proxy solution
>   known as a "Frootbox" to capture the errors and redirect its clients
>   to navigation pages that may contain sponsored listings and
>   algorithmic results. If a user clicks on a sponsored link, Barefruit
>   and the ISP share the revenue.

So you can chillax - these guys work with your Internet Service Provider.

If you still don't feel happy about these guys, [set up a firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) and use [iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) to block one ip or [a group](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2213609)

Best of luck !

Comment: Just checked, Barefruit seems legit. I appreciate your help!

Comment: "Wikipedia does not have an article with this exact name."

Comment: @endolith  Looks like it has been deleted: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Log/delete&page=Barefruit

Comment: Barefruit appears to be part of Verizon's DNS assistance program, where any DNS result that returns 'NXDOMAIN' gets forwarded to Barefruit to provide DNS suggestions and also to collect and sell information about your browsing habits. So, yes it's "legit" but a little shady.

I'm not sure of the settings for non-US service, but there is a way to opt out of DNS suggestions in the States, by changing the DNS server IP used from .12 to .14 in your Verizon router. See here for more details:
https://www.verizon.com/support/residential/internet/home-network/settings/opt-out-of-dns-assist